# Check column data has spaces in it

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-formatting, detect

Is there a way to check if values in column has spaces in it?

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("new ", "Old"), b = c("Cta", "df"))
```

We have space in "a" column. So expected output to be

```
     a   b   spaceInCola
1 new  Cta   TRUE
2  Old  df   FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
asd %>% 
  mutate(spaceInCola = str_detect(a, "\\s"))

#     a   b spaceInCola
#1 new  Cta        TRUE
#2  Old  df       FALSE
```

Useful to use `dplyr` in that case if you want to check over multiple columns:

```r
asd %>% 
  mutate(across(a:b, ~ str_detect(.x, "\\s"),
                .names = "SpaceInCol{col}"))

#      a   b SpaceInCola SpaceInColb
# 1 new  Cta        TRUE       FALSE
# 2  Old  df       FALSE       FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Here's an easy way with `grepl`:

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("new ", "Old"), b = c("Cta", "df"))

asd$spaceInCola <- grepl(' ', asd$a)

asd
#>      a   b spaceInCola
#> 1 new  Cta        TRUE
#> 2  Old  df       FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Option using `sapply`:

```r
asd$spaceInCola <- sapply(asd$a, \(x) grepl(' ', x))
asd
#>      a   b spaceInCola
#> 1 new  Cta        TRUE
#> 2  Old  df       FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Option using `sapply` with the sum of TRUE's. This is for row-wise checking:

```r
asd$spaceInCola <- sapply(asd, \(x) as.logical(sum(grepl(' ', x))))
asd
#>      a   b spaceInCola
#> 1 new  Cta        TRUE
#> 2  Old  df       FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Not sure whether `sapply` is necessary here since `grepl` is vectorized

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`:

```
asd$spaceInColA <- str_detect(asd[,1], " ")
```

Or with `stringi`:

```
asd$spaceInColA <- stri_detect_fixed(asd[,1]," ")
```

Outupt is the same for both functions:

```
> asd
     a   b spaceInColA
1 new  Cta        TRUE
2  Old  df       FALSE
```